# Can ffmpeg read filters from a text file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a very long list of `drawtext` and `overlay` filters (several thousand). I'm running into an issue of hitting my operating system's hard limit for total command length (~131k characters). Can I work around this in any way?

Sample command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex {150k characters} output.mp4`

Does `ffmpeg` allow a text file containing the `-filter_complex` value?

Something like:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex /path/to/filters.txt output.mp4`

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `-filter_complex_script` option.

From the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> This option is similar to `-filter_complex`, the only difference is
>   that its argument is the name of the file from which a complex
>   filtergraph description is to be read.